# Eigenvalues from determinant calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Going through Dr Strang's textbook on Linear Algebra, I am trying to understand one of the sample questions to calculate the eigenvalues of a matrix. Using

$$
\det(A-\lambda I)=0
$$

with $\det(A)$ as the product of the pivots. Therefore for the given matrix A

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2&-1\\
-1&2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

the pivots would be

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2-\lambda&-1\\
-1&2-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
= \lambda^2-4\lambda +4 = (2-\lambda)(2-\lambda)
$$

giving a single eigenvalue of $2$.

However the book says $\lambda^2-4\lambda +3$ giving eigenvalues of $1$ and $3$. I have checked a later edition of the textbook which has the same content and do not find this listed in any errata online. Therefore I am not sure if my understanding is incorrect or if this is really is an error.

Comment: There is no error. $\det$ is not the product of the pivots.

Comment: $\det$ is $(2-\lambda)^2 - (-1)^2 = (2-\lambda -1)(2-\lambda +1)$

Comment: I see, I need to use $\det=ad-bc$. Thanks

Comment: However product of pivots can be a kind of estimate of determinant. How reliable depends on the Geršgorin disc radii.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant of

\begin{bmatrix}
2-\lambda&-1\\
-1&2-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}

is  $\lambda^2-4\lambda +4 -(-1)(-1) = (\lambda-1)(\lambda-3)$, so your book is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Chenyang is right in his answer about the determinant. However the product of pivots are the product of the midpoints of it's [Geršgorin discs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem). Depending on how large diagonal elements are compared to off-diagonal elements the matrix is this can give a more or less accurate *estimate* of the determinant.